# Closing ItemView without Marionette's RegionManager

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a region `App.modalRegion` where I show `TopicView`, a CompositeView that shows a list of lectures links in the `sidebar` and a `content` area that plays the lecture video when a link is clicked. Everything works fine, but the `VideoItemView` is not closed when another link is clicked on.

My question is: When the video content is changed on `'.link'` click, is there (one of those Marionette's magical ways) the previous `VideoItemView` could be closed **without using a sub-region and layout** inside the `App.modalRegion` region. Here's the code:

```
App.modalRegion.show( new TopicView({ model: topicModel }) );

TopicView = new Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend( {

  template: tpls.TopicTpl,

  ui: {
    sidebar: "#topic-sidebar",
    content: "#topic-content"
  },

  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
  },

  onRender: function(){
    this.showContent();

    var collection = this.model.get('lectures'),
      that = this;

    this.ui.sidebar.on('click','.link',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var sno = $(this).data("sno");

      var vid = new VideoItemView({
        model: collection.get(sno),
        lec_sno: sno
      });

      that.ui.content.html(
        vid.render().el
      );
    });
  },

  showContent : function() {

    var list = new LectListCol({ 
      collection: this.model.get('lectures')
    });

    this.ui.sidebar.html(
      list.render().el
    );
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a property to your `TopicView` that would reference your `currentVideoItemView`.

Just before you render the new `VideoItemView`, you would check to see if `currentVideoItemView` is an instance of `VideoItemView`.

Then you would call the `close` method on the `currentVideoItemView`, render your new `VideoItemView` and then set the `currentVideoItemView` again.